# Java - Open cmd and redirect my System.out's to that cmd window

Tags: java, cmd

I want to open a cmd window and use it to show  my logs such as `System.out.print` . It will be same as opening jar file from cmd window but i want a shortcut where cmd window will be opened. I am using a trick where i open cmd then restart my program with cmd batch but it needs restart and args param. ALso **in my workaround i can't debug too**!..My bad workaround below;

```
 if(args.length != 0){
        //**actual program**
   }else{
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(DefaultValues.startBatchFile);

        if(!DefaultValues.debugMode) {
            Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
            String currentPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            builder.directory(new File(currentPath));
        }else{
            builder.directory(new File(DefaultValues.debugPath));
        }

        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.start();
    }
```

Comment: Does it really take too much time to implement what i want? :(

Comment: I know not java but I do know Windows. Programs marked as console automatically create a console. Programs marked GUI do not have ANY GUI elements (programs have to create them) and Windows do not create a console for them. MS scripts have two versions of the runtime - GUI and Console. Therefore use Javac or compile as a plain exe.

Comment: Well, you don’t need to “restart” the app, window can just be opened and closed, you also don’t lose debugging capability, so, from perspective, I’d take less time and cause less issues to embed a “log” window